# Repair Bootcamp after creating new partitions

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, leopard

I have an iMac 9.1 with OS X Leopard on it. A while ago I used Bootcamp to install Windows 7 on it. For several reasons I now wanted to add two more 
partitions to the disk using the Disk Utility. I now have four partitions:

1. Macintosh HD
2. UBUNTU
3. WINDOWS DAT
4. BOOTCAMP

Number 2 and 3 are empty.
When restarting the computer and holding the alt-key, I only get booting into Mac OS as an option. I already found out that this probably due to a mixup between GBT and MBR.

I tried using GPT fdisk to repair this by writing a new hybrid MBR, but no success.

This is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *596.2 Gi   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         200.0 Mi   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            454.6 Gi   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data UBUNTU                  50.0 Gi    disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data WINDOWS DAT             49.9 Gi    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                41.0 Gi    disk0s5
```

This is the output of `sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0`:

```
gpt show: disk0: mediasize=640135028736; sectorsize=512; blocks=1250263728
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 1250263727
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   953312872      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   953722512      631152         
   954353664   104857600      3  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1059211264      262144         
  1059473408   104595456      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1164068864      262144         
  1164331008    85932032      5  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1250263040         655         
  1250263695          32         Sec GPT table
  1250263727           1         Sec GPT header
```

and this is the output of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 77825/255/63 [1250263728 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  954353663] <Unknown ID>
 2: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 954353664 -  104857600] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [1059473408 -  104595456] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [1164331008 -   85932032] HPFS/QNX/AUX
```

Here you can see the result of my GPT fdisk try. I tried to put `disk0s1`and `disk0s2`into the MBR as partition 1 and then `disk0s3` to `disk0s5` as partitions 2 to 4, where the last one is flagged as bootable.

Now comes my question:

How can I fix this?

"Fix" means keeping the two new partitions and being able to boot into Windows 7 on the Bootcamp partition. I should note that I do not have the Win 7 DVD at hand (it was a burn-your-own-install-dvd student version, it seems that the dvd got lost over the years).